# Mobile Keyboard/Inspector throws off Height: 100% CSS

Tags: reactjs, flexbox, responsive

I have a teeny-tiny page deployed @ http://pinkbook.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/

I am exercising my responsive design, I'm using `flexbox` with a few components from Material-UI, which are designed with `display: block` for the most part.

When clicking on the input fields for email or password, on mobile, the keyboard pops up and causes the content and layout to be distorted. The 100% height of HTML/Body no longer seems consistent, and some of my buttons that have margin rules in place now escape their container and bleed into whitespace that isn't covered in HTML/Body.

Please glance at that URL and either take a look from a mobile browser, or open your inspector and look at the bottom of the page -- there are distinct white areas and mispositioned buttons. How would one adjust the CSS to avoid the whitespace and content misalignment when an input field is focused and the keyboard presents itself?

Comment: Having the exact same issue! How did you solve it? Looking at your example you can scroll the site below, it seems

Comment: Honestly I can't remember. It was definitely a CSS only solution.